# Is there a function/workflow in R or Python to plot characters per position for word comparisons?

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse

I have several words of the same length that I'd like to compare at each position.

### Example

three words "apples" , "banana", "orange"

### Aligned

```
apples
banana
orange
```

### Plotting

I'd like to compare these words on an xy-plot, with the y-axis having the entire alphabet along it (A to Z or Z to A) and the x-axis having each position (read from left to right, position 0 to length(word - 1)). A plotted point indicates the character (y-axis) at the given position (x-axis), and these points are connected together by a line.

Can additional information be included in this plot (e.g., coloring of points based on some other category; size/shape of point based on another category)?

Is there a way to prepare this data in Python/R and to display it in the above way?

---

### What I've tried in R

I've tried making a list that tallies each character per position for each word, however I'm not sure how to iterate over this list to display the characters at each position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an R solution. It should work just fine even if the words have different lengths.

```
x = c("apples", "banana", "orange")
d = data.frame(
  letters = factor(unlist(strsplit(x, "")), levels = letters),
  pos = unlist(lapply(x, function(x) seq(nchar(x)))),
  word = rep(x, times =  nchar(x))
)

ggplot(d, aes(x = pos, y = letters, color = word)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = word)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This can be realized using `matplotlib` for example. You can obtain the y-coordinates via the builtin `ord` function. The alphabet can be obtained from `string.ascii_lowercase` (saves you some typing):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

words = ['apples', 'banana', 'orange']
y_coords = [[ord(c) for c in word] for word in words]

f, ax = plt.subplots()
for word, y in zip(words, y_coords):
    ax.plot(range(len(y)), y, '-o', label=word)
y_range = [ord('a') - 1, ord('z') + 1]
ax.set_ylim(y_range)
ax.set_yticks(range(*y_range))
ax.set_yticklabels(' ' + ascii_lowercase)
ax.grid()
ax.legend()
f.savefig('/tmp/example.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

In R

```
x = c("apples" , "banana", "orange")
graphics.off()
plot(1, xlim = c(1, max(nchar(x))), ylim = c(1, 26), type = "n", yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at = 1:26, labels = letters, las = 2)
invisible(sapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
    s = x[i]
    lines(x = 1:nchar(s), y = match(unlist(strsplit(s, "")), letters),
           col = i)
    points(x = 1:nchar(s), y = match(unlist(strsplit(s, "")), letters),
           col = i, pch = 19)
}))
#legend("topright", legend = x, pch = 19, col = seq_along(x), lty = 1)
```

[image]